# Вывод в input значение JS, JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

Проверяю через регулярные выражения введенные данные на отсутствие каких либо символов кроме чисел. Проверка происходит при каждом отжатии клавиши. Полученное значение не могу вернуть в input.

```
<script>
$('input[type="text"]').keyup(function() {
    let value = $('input[type="text"]').val();
    value = value.replace( /\D/g, "" );
    $('input[type="text"]').innerHTML = value;
});
</script>
```

Comment: А пробовали логировать в консоль результат?  value = value.replace( /\D/g, "" ); вообще что-то возвращает?

Comment: console.log(value);

Comment: а почему значение возвращается в html инпута? а не в value?

Comment: если необходимо поле только для чисел, почему не использовать type=number?

Comment: @SergeySubbotin, регулярное выражение отрабатывает без ошибок, да выводил в консоль.

Если вопрос к регулярке, то тут любое не число \D, заменяется ничем "". Так как есть метка global - g то отрабатывает на всё значение.

Comment: @soledar10, в учебных целях изучения регулярных выражений и изучения библиотеки JQuery.

Comment: @DenVarenik А есть возможность дать input айдишник или класс? и тогда обратиться к нему $("#inputId").innerHTML = value; или $(".inputClass").innerHTML = value;  Я бы так пробовал.  Или еще вариант $("#inputId").val(value);

Comment: @SergeySubbotin, при выводе в консоле находит нужный мне input, так же найдет и по id и по классу, от этого innerHTML отрабатывать не станет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отбрасываем ненужный .innerHTML и возвращаем значение точно в value input'a:

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', (e) => {
 e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, "");
})
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

У **input** есть хороший "слушатель" как *input*. Уверен, так корректнее использовать.